# Clean solution to move yaxis in polar plot

Tags: pgfplots, labels, polarplot

I want to be able to plot the upper half of the attached polar plot (MWE), by setting xmin=0 and xmax=180. This, however, is non-trivial when I at the same time want to have the yaxis with labels and title as illustrated below. Is there a clean way of solving this without rotating the coordinate system (and the ylabel/yticklabels actually follows the replacement of the yaxis)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\xshift{5cm}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        xmin=90,
        xmax=450,
        major tick length=2,
        xtick={90,120,...,420},
        xticklabel={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytick}{mod(\tick,360)}${\mytick}^\circ$},
        grid=both,
        y axis line style={xshift=-\xshift},
        ytick style={xshift=-\xshift},
        yticklabel style={
            xshift=-\xshift-0.3em,
        },  
        ymax=0.5,
        ytick={0,0.1,...,0.5},
        ylabel={Cumbersome label},
        every axis y label/.style={
            xshift=-\xshift-2.5em,
            yshift=1.4cm,
            rotate=90,
            anchor=south,
        },  
        ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,domain=90:450,smooth,blue,samples=1000] {sin(2*x)*cos(2*x)};
    \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In an attempt of providing a clean solution, consider the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\xshift{5cm}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=180,
        major tick length=2,
        xtick={0,30,...,180},
        xticklabel={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytick}{mod(\tick,360)}${\mytick}^\circ$},
        grid=both,
        y axis line style={rotate=-90,yshift=-\xshift},
        ytick style={rotate=-90,yshift=-\xshift},
        yticklabel style={rotate=-90,yshift=-\xshift},  
        ymax=0.5,
        ytick={0,0.1,...,0.5},
        ylabel={Cumbersome label},
        every axis y label/.style={
            xshift=-\xshift,
            rotate=90,
            anchor=south,
        },  
        ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,domain=90:450,smooth,blue,samples=1000] {sin(2*x)*cos(2*x)};
    \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this counts as clean, but rotating things around the axis origin might be an option.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand\xshift{5cm}
    \newcommand\AxisWidth{8cm}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=180,
        scale only axis,  % set width of axis only to 
        width=\AxisWidth, % this value
        major tick length=2,
        xtick={0,30,...,180},
        xticklabel={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytick}{mod(\tick,360)}${\mytick}^\circ$},
        grid=both,
        y axis line style={
           overlay, % added so it doesn't increase the size of the bounding box
           rotate around={90:(current axis.origin)}, % makes it a vertical line through the origin
           yshift=\xshift,  % shift left
           shorten >=\AxisWidth/4, % seemed to shorten line at both ends, so shorten by a quarter of the length
           xshift=\AxisWidth/4,    % and then shift it up
           line cap=rect
           },
        ytick style={rotate=-90,yshift=-\xshift},
        yticklabel style={
           rotate=-90, % first rotate nodes "in place"
           rotate around={90:(current axis.origin)}, % then rotate them around the origin
           xshift=-\xshift, % and move them left
           left, % set a useful anchor
           alias=ytick-\ticknum % give ticklabels nodes aliases
           },  
        ymax=0.5,
        ytick={0,0.1,...,0.51},
        ylabel={Cumbersome label},
        ylabel style={
           at=(current axis.west -| ytick-1.west), % place at y-coord of current axis.west, x-coord of of ytick-1
           left, % set useful anchor
           anchor=south,
           rotate=90
           }
        ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,domain=90:450,smooth,blue,samples=100] {sin(2*x)*cos(2*x)};
    \end{polaraxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is much better, but still has the somewhat arbitrary command "left=2cm" in the ylabel style. I guess this value (2cm), "\AxisWidth" and "\xshift" should all be linked?

Comment: @user2978680 Came up with a workaround for that, see updated answer.

Comment: Smooth! Completing with something like "\def\xshift{1.2*\AxisWidth/2}", and I think this is as good as it gets :)

Comment: How come "\newcommand\temp{2*\baselineskip+\AxisWidth/2}" does not work?

Comment: Separating into "\newcommand\temp{2.5*\baselineskip}" and "\newcommand\xshift{\AxisWidth/2}", and then replacing \xshift by \xshift+\temp solves that problem, but why?

Comment: @user2978680 Don't know, if you want a diagnosis, you could ask a new question about that specifically.